# Two verbs in one sentence? 辞書にある言葉で　出来上がった世界を憎んだ

Tags: grammar, song-lyrics

I came across a line of lyric goes like this:

> 辞書にある言葉で　出来上がった世界を憎んだ

I wonder if there are two independent sentences: 辞書にある言葉で　出来上がった and 世界を憎んだ because there are two verbs and no て-form. And if so, how to make it one whole sentence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

辞書にある言葉で　出来上がった世界 is one big relative clause where 辞書にある言葉 is another relative clause, contained within the bigger one. To make a Japanese relative clause you move the clause behind the noun it modifies (for example 「魚を食べた猫」'the cat *that* ate the fish'. Not that because of this there is no Japanese word for 'that' in this sense.

'([With words in the dictionary] the world made) I hated.' In other words, 'I hated the world (that is) made of words (that are) in the dictionary.' Brackets added to the translation to help you understand how the English sentence uses relative clauses too.